# Execute code within a preset latency in php

Tags: php, timing

I have to execute a piece of code in php and the code must be executed within 5 seconds.

if it is not executed within 5 seconds, a message should be 'echo'. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

get the start time before starting your code and end time after code in timestamp( which is in sec) and get difference after code end

```
$start_time = strtotime(date('d-M-Y g:i:s A'));

----
--- your piece of code
-----

$time_now = strtotime(date('d-M-Y g:i:s A'));

if($time_now-$start_time > 5)
{
     echo "Some thing ";
}
```

Comment: thanks but i dont want the execution time of the code, if the execution time is exceeding 5s, stop execution and echo a message

Comment: you can use this in between of your code after some statement

Comment: I'm have to ping a server and if the server does not response within 5s, an message should be appear. any solution for this

Comment: then you should use timeout. see some of links are there on google for it. https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=php%20ping%20a%20server%20with%20timeout